# Treemap depth control

Tags: angular, d3.js, data-visualization, d3plus, datavisualization.toolkit

I have been trying to implement a treemap in my page.
The issue is I want an external depth control to handle the bifurcations of the treemap.

For example http://dataviva.info/en/build_graph/rais/all/all/all?view=Employment%20by%20Municipality&graph=tree_map

Please see the "depth" selection at the bottom of the above page. Observe how the graph is changing.

is there any way to implement this using d3plus?